# Overflow scroll is not working

Tags: html, css, position

I have three level of divs.
Code snippet:     [jsfiddle.net:divs](https://jsfiddle.net/narusevic/c8wvte7r/1/)

```
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="second-level">
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="second-level top-40">
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>

.div-container{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 576px;
    border: solid 2px #a6a29f;
}

.second-level{    
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.divs {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}

div {
    display: block;
}
```

*div-container*, which has fixed width, contains several *second-level* containers.
These container's width is dynamic. It could be more or less than *div-container* width. If *second-level's* width is more than *div-container's* div, scrollbar should appear (no parent div's width exceeding).
Tried a lot of different display, position and overflow settings, but no success.
Thank you in advance!

P.S. Simply adding

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to div-container does this:
[image: I don't want to second-level exceed div-container width]
I want it to be like I drew in red.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/2yte6tty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful. Sample Below

```css
.div-container{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 576px;
    border: solid 2px #a6a29f;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.second-level{    
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
}

.divs {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 50px;
}

.top-40 {
    top:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="second-level">
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="second-level top-40">
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
    <div class="divs">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Haven't heard about display: flex property. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy it helped. :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put the overflow-x:scroll on the div-container class

Comment: Do you realy need the second-level to be absolute? Because it's working without it.. look : https://jsfiddle.net/c8wvte7r/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
.div-container{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 576px;
    border: solid 2px #a6a29f;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: That also doesn't give desired effect